# How to document UI texts?

Tags: documentation, ux-writing

I'm diving into UX Writing in my company and wondering how to best document the UI texts in our app and portal.

My goal is to have all the UI texts in one place, like a sitemap, where I can easily see which text is used on which pages. This way, if I need to make any changes, I'll know exactly where to update them.

Currently, the dev teams store everything in a JSON file, but I prefer a more visual approach.

Comment: Can you explain why the text(s) are currently all in a JSON file? And are you taking localisation/translations into account?

Comment: This sounds like a job for a spreadsheet (should be possible to exchange with JSON). But jazZRo has some important questions here - you need to know what possibilities to make room for before you build a solution.